# Maximize the browser using Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

In my Angualr2 application, i am using Typescript. I need to maximize the browser when the app is get to run. I have seen [this](https://docs.oseems.com/general/programming/javascript/maximize-browser-window). So in javascript it can be done with

```
         window.moveTo(0, 0);
        window.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height)
```

but i don't know,  **how i can access to the** `window` **object in the** `typescript`?

Comment: downvoters: leave a comment

Comment: Did you read the comments in the article you linked to?

Comment: That's sad. so, what is the solution? @JJJ

Comment: @Salman The solution is open it in a pop-up and cross your fingers or request that your users maximize the window themselves.

Comment: @MikeC Do you mean, there is no direct solution for it? right?

Comment: @Salman In simple terms: yes. An indirect solution would be to try opening your app in a pop-up and try resizing the pop-up. It may or may not work depending on which browser they're using. If it doesn't work, you can't do anything more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript is just a superset of JavaScript so any valid JavaScript is valid TypeScript.

First off, you mentioned installing jQuery. The code you linked to doesn't use jQuery so I don't understand why you would need it.

Second: [`window.resizeTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo) does not work in most cases. Unless you're making a pop-up, it's unlikely it will work at all. In fact, [I just tested it](https://jsfiddle.net/hk468eto/) in Chrome, Edge, Firerfox, and IE11. IE is the only one which worked.

Comment: good answer. i mentioned jQuery, and i meant, i welcome the jQuery answers